# Change of basis by keeping one vector the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

I met an uncommon (to me, at least) change of basis question:

*A linear operator f maps the vector a [2 -1] and b [-3 2] to the vectors p=f(a) = [2 4]
and q=f(b) = [−1 −2]. Find the matrix of f in the basis {a,q}.*

What confuses me is that the target base is {a,q}, not {p,q}. Do I just do as always but keeping vector a without changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do the same as you would usually do. A matrix can be found with respect to any arbitrary basis of your vector space, so this should just work. Note also that $a = (2,-1)$ and $q = (-1,-2)$ are both not standard basis vectors so in that sense the change of basis does not keep a (basis)vector the same.

Indeed the choice of basis seems peculiar and probably you won't often encounter it in applications.